# Show if $D$ is an integral domain, then $D[x]$ is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification, field-theory

I did Exercise 24 from Section 22 of *A First Course in Abstract Algebra, 7th edition* by John B. Fraleigh, and I want to check if my solution is correct. Would anyone be willing to check whether my proof is correct, and if not, is there any way I can improve? Here is the exercise:

> Prove that if $D$ is an integral domain, then $D[x]$ is an integral domain.

Here's what I tried:

**Proof:** Since $D$ is an integral domain, by Theorem 22.2* we have that $D[x]$ is commutative with unity $1\neq 0$. It remains to check if $D[x]$ does not have $0$ divisors.

Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i$ and $g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i x^i$ where $f(x),g(x)\in D[x]$ and $f(x),g(x)\neq 0$. We have that $f(x)g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{i=0}^n a_ib_{n-i}\right)x^n.$ Since $f(x)\neq 0$, there exists some $a_j\neq 0,$ and since $g(x)\neq 0$, there exists some $b_k\neq 0$, so $f(x)g(x)$ has the term $a_j b_k x^{k+j}.$ Since $a_j,b_k\in D$ and $a_j,b_k\neq 0$, $a_jb_k\neq 0$ since there are no $0$ divisors in $D$. Therefore, $f(x)g(x)\neq 0.$ Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are arbitrary, we conclude $D[x]$ has no $0$ divisors, so $D[x]$ is an integral domain. $\blacksquare$

*Theorem 22.2 states: The set $R[x]$ of all polynomials in an indeterminate $x$ with coefficients in a ring $R$ is a ring under polynomial addition and multiplication. If $R$ is commutative, then so is $R[x]$, and if $R$ has unity $1\neq 0,$ then $1$ is also unity for $R[x]$.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should take $a_j$ and $b_k$ not just to be any nonzero coefficients, but as the *highest-degree* nonzero coefficients. Otherwise, other coefficients might interfere.

Comment: But the coefficient of $x^{k+j}$ still could be $0$, isn’t? For example, the coefficient of $x$ in $f(x) = 1+x$ is $1$, and the coefficient of $x$ in $g(x)=1-x+x^2$ is $-1$, but the coefficient of $x^2$ in $f(x)g(x) = 1+x^3$ is $0$.

Comment: @KentaS One also could use the lowest-degree nonzero coefficients to the same effect, but it is traditional to use the highest-degree coefficients.  You're absolutely correct, of course, that the proof as written is not correct but can be corrected in the manner you suggest.

Comment: @KentaS Ah, I see. That's what they did in the solution manual but I wanted to see if my solution was ok. Guess it didn't work for reasons azif00 described.